# Sorting the database result after search

Tags: mysql, database, sorting

My database table is as follows:

Id      Name

1        Jerry

2        Tom and Jerry

3        Jerrymouse

4       Tom

My sql seach statement is as follows:

```
    $sql = "select * from table where Name like %jerry%";
```

When i run the query, the result is as follows the result will be obtained in the same order as above(except Tom). But the result i want is as follows:

Jerry

Jerrymouse

Tom and Jerry

Can anyone help me to display the result in a sorted form as above using sql?

Comment: add `ORDER BY Name DESC`

Comment: `select * from table where Name like %jerry% ORDER BY Name`

Comment: @scibuff Looks like `ASC` to me...

Comment: Review the [MySQL ORDER BY documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html).

Comment: yeah, i always confuse the two when dealing with strings :D

Comment: It would help to specify how you come up with that order. Looks like most people are assuming simply alphabetical, but perhaps are you actully looking for some sort of 'ranking' order - ie how well it matches? If so then MySQL does have Full-Text indexing (so you avoid the use of 'like') - which offers scoring.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the documentation for [sorting rows](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html). In this case, you can try:

```
select * from table where Name like '%jerry%' order by Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 $sql = "select * from table where Name like %jerry% order by Name";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table where Name like '%jerry%' order by Name desc
```

Comment: Oh.. Ok :) Anyways happy that it's useful to you some way.